# Non Associative Array in package.json

Tags: npm, package.json

I need an array of languages in package.json, I've tried:

```
"langs": {
    "en", "es"
 }
```

But it's not valid.

How can I store an array of languages in my package.json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"langs": ["en", "es"]
```

Should work, so just replace your `{` with `[` and `}` with `]`.

Answer (score 2):

Use square brackets [] instead of curly braces {}.

Curly braces are for objects: 
    "dog":{'name':'foobar'}

More info on syntax here: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp